# Limit web-service access to only SMS-verified smart-phones

Tags: iphone, web-services, google-app-engine, encryption, rsa

I have a web service on Google App Engine that an iphone/android app is calling.

I use HTTPS with basic authentication with: mobilenumber:pincode:device_id

The phone number is verified with SMS.

But to secure that hackers arent using the service with other peoples account, when the device is SMS verified, the device is given an RSA public key, with the private key saved on the server (each device has its own set of public/private keys) and when a request is made, the device use the basic authentication but also include the whole string encrypted with the public key, then on the server-side I look up the private key with the device_id, decrypt the encrypted message and make sure it matches the basic authentication string.

The reason of this is that I find the basic authentication to easy to hack (perhaps its not?), the pincode is only 4 digits, so I guess a hacker would have to find out another users device_id somehow,

but maybe the whole RSA thing is an overkill? could I just limit the "server-key" to be a 20 alphanumeric string for each device create on the server and given to the device at the SMS verification? so that it would be: mobilenumber:pincode:device_id:20AlphanumericStringForThisDevice?

Comment: RSA could well be overkill, depending on more details of what hacker attack vectors you are worried about.  If a mobile client is compromised, its RSA public key is transferable to other mobile clients.  If a mobile device is lost or stolen, most security will be defeated by debuggers.  Can one device fake the device_id of another?  Cloning SIM cards appears to be a common crime.  Mobile clients may contain lots of advanced malware, so all your attempts would be more about reducing violation volumes rather than achieving absolute security, which is never possible anyway.

Comment: The device_id can indeed be faked, the hacker however, would have to "guess"/obtain what it is, an example for an ios device id (uuid): 68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067.

Should the phone be compromised I believe it would be fairly easy to hack the users account, only having to guess the four digits for the pincode.

But the uuid is a generate from a standard to be unique using timestamps and so on, so I am not sure how easy it is to guess/obtain. So maybe just use a 25 random alphanumeric string as extra security for good measures?

Comment: If the RSA key and random string can only limit the same kind of attacks (using the web-service on another user's quota), then just using the random string for simplicity and save performance, created by the server (and paired saved with the device id in the database) when the SMS code is sent, might be a good idea? (and also save time on googles app engine)

Comment: Yes, that is simpler but effective against the most probable hack attempts.  Less overkill and overhead, probably appropriate depending on what you or the legitimate user loses in the event of a compromise.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking that. Thanks for the help.